# How to get a Stream object for a remote file on SFTP using SharpSSH library?

Tags: c#, .net, sftp, sharpssh

How can I get a Stream object to read the file that is on SFTP share? 
I see that there is functionality to download a file from SFTP using Sftp class, but I need a Stream object to be able to show the download progress.

Comment: Related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295552/streaming-a-file-from-sharpssh

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with SharpSSH, but [edtFTPnet/PRO](http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpnetpro/overview.html), which is a commercial .NET library supporting SFTP and FTPS, uses a BytesTransferred event that you can subscribe to.

So you regularly get notified of how much has been downloaded or uploaded, and if you grab the size before transferring, you can easily then calculate download progress.

I assume SharpSSH has a similar event you can subscribe to.

Answer (score 0):

Try to download [SSH.NET Library from CodePlex](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/)

This library has a method to download a file

```
public void DownloadFile(string path, Stream output);
```

But I use the method System.Net.WebClient.DownloadData to get a file in sftp server, this method returns a byteArray, you can easyly convert to Stream.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
byte[] file = client.DownloadData(url);
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(file);
```

Hope this helps.